# How to test class components in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am trying some unit testing, I created a sandbox with a fake example https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-hooks-32w6l (in reality I have a form)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { number: 0 };    
  }

  handleSubmit = (number1, number2) => {
    this.setState({ number: this.handleMultiply(number1, number2) })
  }

  handleMultiply = (number1, number2) => {
    return number1 * number2
  }

  render() {
    const { number } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(3, 7)}>       
          <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Multiply" />
        </form>
        <Table number={number} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

So my initial idea was to try to test the multiply function. And did this, which obviously doesn't work

```
import App from "../src/App";

test("Multiply", function() {
  const expected = 21;
  const result = App.handleMultiply(3, 7);
  expect(result).toBe(expected);
});
```

I get

> _App.default.handleMultiply is not a function

Is my approach right? If yes then how do I test the functions? Else, should I test from a user point of view instead of for internal functions (this is what I read)? Should I test for the output on the screen (I don't think this is reasonable)?

Comment: You’re approaching this with the wrong mindset. Instead trigger the form submit then check to make sure state has been updated appropriately including the multiply logic.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky ok, thank you, I will try, and do a more specific question if i get stuck

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky what if the form in a child component and the submit handlers in the parent? Do I need to do integration tests there?

Comment: It may be a matter of opinion but I’d definitely test these separately. The tests for the child would be that on submit it triggers the function passed from the parent via props then also to test that the state renders as you’d expect. For the parent, I’d trigger the event and make sure the state has been updated correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [instance()](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/instance.html) method of `enzyme` to get the instance of React Component. Then, call `handleMultiply` method directly and make the assertion for it. Furthermore, if the `handleMultiply` method has a side-effect or very complicated calculations, you need to make a simple mocked return value for it. It will make an isolated test environment for `handleSubmit` method. This means `handleSubmit` method will not depend on the return value of the real implementation of `handleMultiply` method.

E.g.

`app.jsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Table } from './table';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { number: 0 };
  }

  handleSubmit = (number1, number2) => {
    this.setState({ number: this.handleMultiply(number1, number2) });
  };

  handleMultiply = (number1, number2) => {
    return number1 * number2;
  };

  render() {
    const { number } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(3, 7)}>
          <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Multiply" />
        </form>
        <Table number={number} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

`table.jsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';

export const Table = ({ number: num }) => {
  return <div>table: {num}</div>;
};
```

`app.test.jsx`:

```js
import App from './app';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('59796928', () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<App></App>);
  });
  describe('#handleSubmit', () => {
    it('should pass', () => {
      expect(wrapper.exists()).toBeTruthy();
      wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit');
      expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual({ number: 21 });
    });
  });
  describe('#handleMultiply', () => {
    it('should pass', () => {
      const comp = wrapper.instance();
      const actual = comp.handleMultiply(2, 10);
      expect(actual).toBe(20);
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59796928/app.test.jsx (11.688s)
  59796928
    #handleSubmit
      ✓ should pass (16ms)
    #handleMultiply
      ✓ should pass (9ms)

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |    90.48 |      100 |    85.71 |    94.44 |                   |
 app.jsx   |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 table.jsx |       50 |      100 |        0 |    66.67 |                 4 |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.936s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59796928

Comment: What if the form was in a child component? How would I trigger handleSubmit in the test, other that with a form submit? Thank you